# How to extract text using BeautifulSoup when same tag exist which are not useful

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am doing a little bit of web scraping and I need the text in between the paragraphs `<p>`:

```
div>
<small>147 out of 252 people found the following review useful:</small><br>
<a href="/user/ur0935867/"><img class="avatar" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTkzOTQxMDY2MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA3NjgwMDE@._V1._SX40_SY40_SS40_.jpg" height=${avatar.image.size} width=${avatar.image.size}></a>
<h2>Unbelievable and way overrated</h2>
<img width="102" height="12" alt="3/10" src="http://i.media-imdb.com/images/showtimes/30.gif"><br>
<b>Author:</b>
<a href="/user/ur0935867/">glenmoreland</a> <small>from Holland</small><br>
<small>18 January 2016</small><br>
<p><b>*** This review may contain spoilers ***</b></p>

</div>
<p>
I cannot believe how many people think this is a good movie....watching
a guy struggle to survive for 2 hours ...come on people..I know there
are not many good movies being made but my word....so many things are
unbelievable...the bear attack, carrying a near dead guy out of the
wilderness up a mountain...going over a cliff on a horse and not
getting hurt...spending long periods of time in freezing cold
water.....surviving extreme cold overnight inside a dead horse...my god
the list is endless....and for Leo&#x27;s so called acting don&#x27;t get me
started...a lot of crawling and moaning and groaning....the whole thing
was a letdown and really a waste of time...also tell the director to
back the camera up a bit on those facial close-ups...they were also
ridiculous...trust me save your money and go see The Hateful Eight.
</p>

<div class="yn" id="ynd_3398112">

<form method="get" 

 action="reviews"

>
Was the above review useful to you?
```

I just need the review in between the the `<p>` tag. And in the source code of the page there are many `<p>` tag which does not contain reviews. How can I get the text of the reviews using BeautifulSoup?

Ps : Source code from http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663202/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt

Comment: The question is not clear. How do you identify this interesting <p> tag? Is it enclosed by a tag with specific id or class? Is it always on the same position?

Comment: @RafałRawicki No class or id is there. It is a IMDB website review page, from where I need only the reviews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach would display all of the reviews (and optionally also give you the review title):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests


html = requests.get("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663202/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text)

for div in soup.find_all('div'):
    h2 = div.find('h2')

    if h2:
        p = div.find_next_sibling('p')

        if p:
            print h2.text
            print p.text
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `div` with the `.yn` class is constant in the markup and always appears after the desired `<p>` tag, you can hook up to that element and then use `find_previous_sibling('p')` to get that tag.

You can read more about next and previous sibling in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this?

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.findAll('p'):
        soup_tag = BeautifulSoup(str(tag))
        b_tag = soup_tag.findAll('b')
        if len(b_tag) == 0:
            review = tag

print review
```

or, even better, you could try `find_previous_sibling('p')` or using that `<div class="yn" id="ynd_3398112">` tag.
i noticed that the review is not inside that `<div>` tag, so you could use this info to access the data you're looking for.
sorry, but your question is not clear.

Comment: Thanks. And in the `find_previous_sibling` option do I first need to do `soup.find_all("div" , class_ ="yn")` and then do `find_previous_sibling('p')`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Each review is an immediate child `<p>` tag below the `<div id="tn15content">` tag, so:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1663202/reviews?ref_=tt_ov_rt').content)

content = soup.find('div', id='tn15content')
reviews = content.find_all('p', recursive=False)[:-1]    # selects immediate children only
```

The only hassle is that an extra `<p>` is matched, that being the `Add another review` link. That should always be the last item in `reviews`, so you can slice if off as shown above.

This will give you a list of all the review paragraph tags. Finally, to get the text:

```
reviews = [tag.text for tag in reviews]
```